# How to configure php-fpm for php 5.6 and apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm

I installed php 5.6, apache 2.2 and php-fpm on my centos 6.6 by using repo from

https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/

I follow this instruction abd try to make php-fpm work
http://www.garron.me/en/linux/apache-mpm-worker-php-fpm-mysql-centos.html

but there are something different from the tutorial:

- the fcgi module conf file location is in /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf
- there is no /var/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi in such location
- there is no /var/run/php5-fpm.sock in such location

fcgid.conf

```
# This is the Apache server configuration file for providing FastCGI support
# through mod_fcgid
#
# Documentation is available at
# http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html

LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so

# Use FastCGI to process .fcg .fcgi & .fpl scripts
AddHandler fcgid-script fcg fcgi fpl

# Sane place to put sockets and shared memory file
FcgidIPCDir /var/run/mod_fcgid
FcgidProcessTableFile /var/run/mod_fcgid/fcgid_shm
```

## udpate

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
  ScriptAlias /fcgi-bin/ /usr/bin/
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddHandler php-fastcgi .php
    Action php-fastcgi /fcgi-bin/php-cgi
    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/bin/php-cgi -host 127.0.0.1:9000
</IfModule>
```

Anyone know how to config? There no php-fpm info show in phpinfo, and i use echo php_sapi_name();, it returns 'cgi-fcgi'

And i tried remove  , there is an error 
Invalid command 'FastCgiExternalServer', perhaps misspelled or defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using fcgid module but not using mod_fastcgi, there is no FastCgiExternalServer, directive. but i don't know how to make fcgid and php-fpm together.

Answer (score 1):

i finally use nginx work with php-fpm, while the apache can keep opening